# Licensing a multi-lingual site using different domains

Tags: localization, multi-environment, license, multi-domain

I'm building a site for a multinational company. I have domains set up like this example:

**acme.com** (main portal site, different from local sites, but also aggregating content from all local sites)
**acmelocal.de**,
**acmelocal.fr**,
**acmelocal.co.uk** ... (local sites using the same structure only different languages)

I want to run everything on the same Craft install to be able to share data. I'll enable certain sections for main portal site only and certain for local sites only - from what I've read, Craft could handle that ... right?

How do I license this? I'm thinking I can buy a pro license for "acme.com" and use all local sites as locales of the main site. Would this work?

I'm running everything on a custom server, so I can set up all the domain stuff etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the official answer from Brandon, here is the summary for anyone that might be in a similar situation:

I can do what I need with only one pro license

- the main portal (acme.com) will run the "en" locale
- additional domains will use different locales (en-uk for UK, etc.)
- this will work even better in Craft 3.0 - there will be a support for "portal" and separate locales
- each domain can have its own URL, templates and content
- I will need to access all administration from a single domain (content editors in another country will have to use acme.com for editing their acmelocal.co.uk)

I will develop on a separate domain first (acme.com is currently live with old site), but I can [transfer](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-transferring) the license easily to acme.com when site is finished.

I can use any local domain for development with this license - more detail [here.](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain)

Thanks, Brandon!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, and it's certainly worth getting this checked by the Craft guys themselves, Craft is licensed per install. So if you just have one core Craft install and several domains pulling content from that, you only need the one license.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm thinking too. I'll send a presales question to the Craft team to be sure.